# How do we do source transformation in complex circuits to get one source

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, circuits

I have a problem in analysing complex circuits by source transformation like this circuit:

[image: Schematic]

For the previous circuit, if the independent source of the simplified circuit is a voltage source, what is its value in volts, so how can I use source transformation to convert these sources into one source?

I reduced the two 100 ohm resistors on the right to 50 then converted the two amp current source into a voltage source , then I converted the voltage source on the left to a current source then reduced the two 50 ohm resistors onto 25 ...  Here was the circuit after this work. I didn't know how to get further than that, to have only one independent source.

[image: Simplified circuit]

Comment: Please edit your schematic to include desgnators for each component and names for each node so we can discuss it clearly.

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Please fix your title to describe the problem you're having. It should tell us something about what it actually is. Then, in your question, please describe what you've tried so far. Questions that very much look like homework are usually closed as not deserving any effort on our side if the asker can't articulate what exactly they've done and where they're stuck – otherwise, we probably can't help you understand what you're doing.

Comment: You have not told us what you are trying to calculate or shown any effort.

Comment: Sorry guys i have edited it .. i didn't know rules

Comment: @AnasAlaa You have four nodes in your original schematic. Which two nodes are to be the final remaining two? I could make an assumption, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 0):

When you transform a voltage source with a resistor in series, the result is a current source with that same resistor in parallel. Consider the circuit below with the nodes labeled:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWGXgB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left, the voltage source (10 V) with the 50 Ω resistor is equivalent to a current source of 0.2 A in parallel with a 50 Ω resistor. Between nodes **A** and **C**, we have two 50 Ω resistors that can also be transformed to a 25 Ω equivalent. Also, since we have another current source between nodes **A** and **C**, we can sum the current sources using the positive reference as the current going from **C** to **A**.

For convenience, considering the right side of the circuit, this last setup for the left side can be transformed in a voltage source with a resistor in series (pay attention to the polarity of the sources):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO3bkm.png)</sup>

Now, on the right side, those 2 100 Ω resistor can be expressed as 50 Ω equivalent and him and the current source between nodes **B** and **C** can be interchanged for the equivalent:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKNFcl.png)</sup>

With this last step, the circuit can be shown as a combination of the previous schematics and the circuit with only one independent source is on the right:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Cywo.png)</sup>

---

edit:

As the user "jonk" mentioned in his comment below your question, be aware that this result is a general one. Another circuit could be the equivalent you are looking for by using the Thévenin/Norton equivalents, that may vary depending on wich pair of nodes you want your equivalent to be seen. The result i've shown you in the last schematic would be a Thévenin equivalent on nodes **A** and **B** and the one with just one independent source on the right would be a equivalent using Req = (Rth + 100) = 175 Ω.

Comment: Thanks for your help but how can I get a different simplification from different terminals ? Shouldn't it be the same for all the circuits?